# What does the spatial frequency domain look like after the Fourier transform of a real array?

Tags: c, fft, frequency, fftw, nyquist

I have an array with N purely real points representing a spatial function:

[f_0, f_1, f_2, ... , f_{N-1}]

The function values are spaced in with a distance dx.

Therefore the Nyquist frequency is given by f_N = 1/(2*dx)

I calculate the Fourier transform of the array in C using FFTW2, with the function for purely 1d real inputs rfftw. This leads to only N/2 independent complex numbers, which are stored in a "half complex array":

[r_0, r_1, .... r_{N/2}, i_{N+1}/2-1 , ..., i_2, i_1],
where r denotes the real and i the imaginary part.

Now I would like to know what the frequency domain of this array looks like.
Is r_{N/2} the value at f_N or (f_N/)2?

I already have the code and it seems to work, i just don't know how to interpret the frequency axis.

Comment: You can figure it out by creating an input that's a pure sine wave of a known frequency. Then the FFT output is a single non-zero value at that frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is confused. If your input is

```
[f_0, f_1, f_2, …, f_{N-1}]
```

then `f_n` is the input value at position `n`, it is not a position itself. The inputs are at integer indices `n = 0 … N-1`. Thus the question asking about “the value at f_N” makes no sense.

The FFTW half-complex output is:

```
[r_0, r_1, r_2, …, r_{N/2}, i_{(n+1)/2-1}, …, i_2, i_1]
```

Here, `r_n + i * i_n` is the value at position `n`. Frequencies are the integer indices `n = 0 … N-1`. The Nyquist frequency is related to `N`, not `f_N` (which is not even defined in your input!). It is given by `N/2.0`.

If you assume a certain sampling `dx` in your input, such that the sample at position `n` has a `x = n*dx`, then you can also translate frequency bins to physical frequencies, with `df = 1/(N*dx)`. Thus, the frequency at index `n` is `n/(N*dx)`. With the understanding that the value for frequency `n/(N*dx)` is equal to that for `(n+k*N)/(N*dx)`, with `k` any positive or negative integer (from which you can obtain the negative frequencies that many expect to find in a Fourier transform).

Comment: sorry, my notation is indeed very bad. Since i refer to the Nyquist frequency with f_N (lets call it Fnq now), and the input also denoted by f_i. From your answer I understand, that the Fourier coefficient r_N/2 + i i_N/2 would be the coefficient corresponding to the Nyquist frequency Fnq = 1/(2*dx) ?

Comment: @madde That’s right.

Comment: Frequencies are also commonly indicated by the Greek letter nu, if that helps with notation